# Loop through local storage and if element exist just update it, if not add it to local storage

Tags: javascript, function, loops, conditional-statements, local-storage

I am making a fake e-commerce site, where I am saving the products in local storage. I want to make a function where if I click the add to cart button, first it will check if the item already exists in the local storage, if yes just update it's quantity property, if not push it to local storage.
I managed it on my index.html page, but for some reason I can't figure it out on details page where only one product is displayed.

This is my code that works on index.html

```js
function listAllProducts() {
    http.get(productsURL).then((products) => {

        ui.showAllProducts(products);
        ui.onLoadCounter();

        document.querySelector('.card-container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

            if (e.target.classList.contains('add-to-cart-btn')) {
                let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
                let id = e.target.getAttribute('id');
                for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                    if (id == products[i].id) {
                        const itemQt = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')[i].value;
                        if (cart === null) {
                            cart = [];
                            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
                        }
                        if (cart) {
                            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
                            if (!cart[i]) {
                                cart.push(products[i]);
                            }
                            else if (cart[i].id == products[i].id) {
                                cart[i].qt = Number(cart[i].qt) + Number(itemQt);
                            };
                            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
                        }
                        ui.showSuccessMessage(`${products[i].name} added to cart`, container);
                        ui.cartCounter();
                    };
                };
            };
        });
    });
};
```

This works fine, and updates everything correctly, probably a cleaner code could be written but it works, and it's good for me atm.

UPDATE: I tested a little bit, on my index page, the first function, will add the product to the cart, if I want to update it, it will just add it one more time to local storage, and at the third add will update everything accordingly so I have a little issue with this as well

This is the details page code, where I have an issue, if I add the loop and check a condition, either the product will be pushed as many times as long my localstorage length is, or everything blocks and nothing is pushed in the local storage.

```js
document.querySelector('.details-add-to-cart-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
            const itemQt = document.getElementById('details-input').value;
            if (cart) {
                cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
                // for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                //     if () {
                //         cart.push(product);
                //         console.log('if')
                //     } else if (cart[i].id == product.id) {
                //         console.log('else')
                //         cart[i].qt = Number(cart.qt) + Number(itemQt);
                //     }
                // }
                product.qt = Number(itemQt);
                cart.push(product);
                localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
            };
            ui.showSuccessMessage(`${product.name} added to cart`, detailsContainer);
            ui.cartCounter();
        });
```

Basically I want on both pages to be able to check if the item is already in the local storage, if not then save it to local storage, if it already exists, update the quantity property  += valueFromInput

Comment: Why you test cart variable before use it?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I am not, I have this before the function
  let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
        if (cart === null) {
            cart = [];
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
        };

Comment: For real in the last code you test if(cart) before use it